# Create Public/Shared Mailbox on OS X Server 10.9.5 with Dovecot 2.2.5

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mac-osx-server

how can I create a Public/Shared Mailbox on OS X Server?
This Mailbox should be available to all authenticated Users on my network and should be automatically subscribed into a folder "Public" in the Mailbox folder structure.
The folder structure in the IMAP inbox should look similar to this:

```
Inbox
  |- User-Folder1
  |- User-Folder2
Send
Deleted
Public
  |- Public-Mailbox-1
  |- Public-Mailbox-2
  |- Public-Mailbox-3
```

What I have done so far:

- I created a User in the LDAP-Directory with an email address "accounts@domain.de" <- Only as workaround to get a mailbox
- I modified this file: /Library/Server/Mail/Config/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf and added this lines at the end:

  ```
  namespace {
      type = public
      separator = .
      prefix = Public.
      location = maildir:/Volumes/Data/Library/Server/Mail/Data/mail/users/accounts/
      subscriptions = yes
      list = yes
      mailbox Public {
              auto = subscribe
      }
  }
  ```

When I login into my IMAP account on the server via webmail (roundcube) I can see the folder in the IMAP "Manage folders" but I can not subscribe to it.
Has anyone an idea how I can get this?

Is it also possible not to create an LDAP User, to get an Mailbox for some special email addresses (accounts, info)?

Thanks Oliver

Version Numbers:
OS X 10.9.5
Server App 3.2.1 (clean install no update)
Postfix:
postconf -d | grep mail_version
mail_version = 2.9.4
Dovecot:
sudo dovecotd --version
2.2.5

Info:
Also posted here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26829189

Answer (score 0):

At least with 10.10, the ACL plugin is enabled, so I believe you will have to declare some permissions for the folder.

Inside /Volumes/Data/Library/Server/Mail/Data/mail/users/accounts/, add a file named `dovecot-acl` and add ACL rules as per http://wiki2.dovecot.org/ACL.

In my case, I wanted all users to have non-admin access, so my file contains this one line:

```
anyone lrwstipe
```

Also, I'm not sure you want `subscriptions=yes`. If that's `no`, then the subscriptions to that folder are managed by the parent, which is each users' account.